# JQuery val() not working after updating JQuery version

Tags: jquery

After upgrading to jquery 1.7.2 i noticed that calling the val() operation is no longer working consistently for me.

The following line of code will always work on the older version of jquery the application was using (1.4.4) whereas on jquery 1.7.2 it does not work

```
var someVal = $("input:hidden[name=Some value withspaces_val]").val();
```

Any ideas of What is causing this to fail? Thanks

Comment: Was that selector ever officially "valid"? In any case, please investigate more to see if it's the `val()` that "isn't working" or if the selector doesn't match .. `$(selector).length == 0` implies that nothing was matched (and the match failed in this case). Then update the title/question with this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried $("input:hidden[name='Some value withspaces_val']")